# EXCEL VBA: How to convert dd/mm/yy into yyyy.mm.dd

Tags: vba, excel, date, replace, format

I want to change format of date form dd/mm/yyyy into yyyy.mm.dd .

```
sub m()
dim date1 as date
dim date2 as date
date1= #1/1/2008#
date2= #1/1/2008#
for conteo = date1 to date2 
conteo = Format$(conteo, "yyyy.mm.dd")
sheets(1).range("A1").value= conteo
next conteo
end sub
```

in the line as below:

```
 conteo = Format$(conteo, "yyyy.mm.dd")
```

It converts but it has quotation around the date and when I change "yyyy.mm.dd" into yyyy.mm.dd in format function I face with "object required" error.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to change the format in VBA?  Wouldn't it be much, much simpler to just change the format of the cell that is *displaying* the date?

Comment: because I want to run the formula below into macro vba and I want use conteo (it is date) as variable in it and it`s format must be yyyy.mm.dd :                                      "=INDEX($H$2:$H$23393,MATCH(DATE(" & conteo & ")& " & j & ",$D$2:$D$23393&$F$2:$F$23393,0))"

Comment: You're more likely to get better answers if you describe the underlying issue then (and provide a data sample).  That said, I would avoid using string based matching for date lookups.

Comment: I asked 3 questions with a sample of my data but nobody answered me, so It made me to ask multiple questions individually of my work. thanks anyway

Comment: That's sounds like a better way to get the answers that you are *looking for* instead of the answers *you need*.  If the dates are stored in Excel as dates and not strings, you can still do lookups with dates or even numbers.

Comment: Where is `conteo` declared, and what type is it?

Comment: Mr comintern please suppose that I want convert this formula below into macro and consider the date is changing in loop in macro how you write it ?!  the formula :    =INDEX($H$2:$H$23393,MATCH(DATEVALUE("1/1/2008")& 1,$D$2:$D$23393&$F$2:$F$23393,0))

Comment: Mr Mug I even declared the conteo as date and variant but it does not work.

Comment: If the values in Excel are dates and `conteo` is a `Date`, you can use a numeric value instead of a string and let Excel worry about the conversions:  `"=INDEX($H$2:$H$23393,MATCH(" & CLng(conteo) & " & " & j & ",$D$2:$D$23393&$F$2:$F$23393,0))"`.  If you *don't* have date types in the match range or `conteo` is something other than a `Date`, it's a completely different problem.

Comment: No It declared as date. I did what you said but I face with error . The error is "Unable to set the FormulaArray property of the Range class".  and the code I used is :  `Sheets(1).Range("J1").FormulaArray = "=INDEX($H$2:$H$23393,MATCH(" & CLng(conteo) & " & " & j & ",$D$2:$D$23393&$F$2:$F$23393,0))"`

Answer (score 2):

First thing you are using same variable as loop ctr and storage for formatted string.

Also drop $ from format. (Or not, see the reasons explained by @thunderframe in the comments.)

You will see quotes (") during debug cause format returns a string , but when you put down the value in cell, it will vanish.

```
Sub m()
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim date2 As Date
    date1 = #1/1/2008#
    date2 = #1/1/2008#
    For conteo = date1 To date2
        strDate = Format(conteo, "yyyy.mm.dd")
        Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = strDate
    Next conteo
End Sub
```

Also, as you have got the date1 and date2 as `Date` type, another and better approach will be.

```
Sub m()
    Dim date1 As Date
    Dim date2 As Date
    date1 = #1/1/2008#
    date2 = #1/1/2008#
    For conteo = date1 To date2
        Sheets(1).Range("A1").NumberFormat = "YYYY.MM.DD"
        Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value2 = conteo
    Next conteo
End Sub
```

Comment: Why drop the $? `Format$` should be preferred over `Format` in this instance because you will *always* get a `String`.

Comment: Not to start an argument but please tell me what difference do you see in the output for `MsgBox TypeName(Format(Date, "mmddyy"))` and `MsgBox TypeName(Format$(Date, "mmddyy"))`.  Also there's no advatange of type conversion in terms  of performance, run a loop between  `date1 = #1/1/2008#` and     `date2 = #1/1/3020#` with and without $, you will get the same run-time. so why use $. Its looks fancy, no doubt there. but thats it in this case.:)

Comment: You should always prefer a strongly typed function result where it is appropriate. If you're trying to format a field value that might be Null, use `Format`. If you're trying to format a date that you know will *always* have a value (and should always return a String), use `Format$`. You will get performance improvements, use less memory and avoid the need for implicit conversions when passing the return variable to procedures that expect a string.

Comment: Performance improvement: I checked but didn't see any difference.

Comment: Are you using a `HighPerformanceCounter`? `Timer()` won't give you the granularity you need. Granted, the performance will be very minor for a single function result, but when you scale your code to handle millions of strings instead of millions of variants, you will notice the difference.

Comment: If you really want performance, you might be better off bypassing the `Fomat$` alias and using the *hidden but valid* COM method `VBA.[_B_str_Format](now(),"yyyy.mm.dd")`

Comment: Thank you @cyboashu for your answer, but in the first section of your answer that you said it should put down in cell to eliminate the quotation but I want put it down in a variable such conteo, I want to use conteo in yyyy.mm.dd format in another line of my macro . How can I do it ?!

Comment: @MajidJavanmard your code should not give a damn about the string representation of a date value - that's a concern for the spreadsheet to have (e.g. number formats). You're making your life crippingly complicated for no reason if you're working with `Date` values as if they were `String` values. Also use `Option Explicit` and **declare your variables**. `conteo` needs to be defined somewhere, e.g. `Dim conteo As Date`.